Merging multiple similar Matrix fields into one
I recently inherited a client’s Craft CMS project where the original developer has created a lot of redundancies, unnecessarily duplicating sections and doing almost identical Matrix fields for each section. Certain Matrix fields have absolutely identical blocks fields in them, something that could have been easily solved by using conditionals, etc.
Of course I could build one "ultimate" new Matrix field to replace all the old ones, however since the site is quite content heavy that would mean all the old Matrix fields’ content like arrays of images, entries, texts, etc. would have to be migrated over to the new fields.
My question: Is there an easy solution, plugin, practice (...) how you would handle this problem without having to manually copy/replicate content from the old Matrix fields?
P.S.: This project is running on Craft 4 and I have no experience with 5 yet. Currently reading the upgrade instructions there is a lot of talk regarding field merging during the process – could this be a solution?
